# sum up a column in text file - bash

Tags: bash

the text file

student.txt

```
jane,good,3
bob,bad,2.6
annie,good,2.8
dan,bad,2
```

first I tried to print all the good student which is successful

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS=, read -r -a array; do
   [[  "${array[1]}" == "good"  ]] || continue
   printf "%s \n" "${array[0]}" is a ${array[1]} student"
   done  <  "student.txt"
```

output

```
jane is a good student
annie is a good student
```

next I also want to sum up all the numbers of the third column in the text file after printing the types of student and it was not successful

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS=, read -r -a array; do
   [[  "${array[1]}" == "good"  ]] || continue
   printf "%s \n" "${array[0]}" is a ${array[1]} student"

   for n in "${array[2]}"; do
      total=$( "$total +=$n" | bc )
      echo $total
   done
done  <  "student.txt"
```

output

```
jane is a good student
+=3: command not found
annie is a good student
+=2.8: command not found
```

expected output

```
jane is a good student
annie is a good student
total = 5.8
```

As I am new to bash scripting , I need to seek help from you guys.

Oh another thing, I can't seem to make good use of awk utility.

even if I tried a simple statement using awk
e.g

```
awk -F","  "{print $1}"  "student.txt"
```

by right if I am not wrong it should return something like this

output

```
good
bad
good
bad
```

but instead it returns me the whole value of the textfile which I have no idea why

my output for awk -F","   "{print $1}"   "student.txt"

```
jane,good,3
bob,bad,2.6
annie,good,2.8
dan,bad,2
```

so I guess any suggestion use awk method is out.

Comment: bash can only do integer arithmetics.

Comment: `so I guess any suggestion use awk method is out.`. People will still suggest `awk` as it's best for this kind of requirements, see @Kent's reply. I suggest you try practicing awk syntax rather than running away from it.

Comment: @jkshah alright I will give it a try again

Answer (score 4):

try this one-liner:

```
awk -F, '$2=="good"{print $1" is good";s+=$3}END{print "total:"s}' file
```

outputs:

```
jane is good
annie is good
total:5.8
```

Comment: OP says no `awk`, still I would have written the similar ans :) Although I like `$2~/good/`, more generic I guess.

Answer (score 0):

This should do (no `awk`):

```
#!/bin/bash
total=0
while IFS=, read -r -a array; do
    [[  "${array[1]}" == "good"  ]] || continue
    printf "%s is a %s student\n" "${array[@]:0:2}"
    total=$(bc <<< "$total+${array[2]}")
done < "student.txt"
echo "$total"
```

Now this forks on `bc` for each student. Instead, you could abuse IFS as so:

```
#!/bin/bash
total=()
while IFS=, read -r -a array; do
    [[  "${array[1]}" == "good"  ]] || continue
    printf "%s is a %s student\n" "${array[@]:0:2}"
    total+=( "${array[2]}" )
done < "student.txt"
# Abusing IFS, I know what I'm doing!
IFS="+" bc <<< "${total[*]}"
```

`:)`

Or, without IFS abuse and not saving data in memory in an array:

```
#!/bin/bash
{
    while IFS=, read -r -a array; do
        [[  "${array[1]}" == "good"  ]] || continue
        printf >&2 "%s is a %s student\n" "${array[@]:0:2}"
        printf "%s+" "${array[2]}"
    done < "student.txt"
    echo "0"
} | bc
```

**Remark.** In the last case, we have to artificially add a 0.

**Exercise.** Use `dc` instead of `bc`.

Answer (score 0):

Pure Bash. The missing floating point arithmetic is emulated.

```
total=0
while IFS=, read -r -a array
do
  [[  "${array[1]}" == "good"  ]] || continue
  printf "%s \n" "${array[0]} is a ${array[1]} student"

  [[ "${array[2]}" =~ ([0-9])(\.([0-9]))? ]]
  (( total += 10*${BASH_REMATCH[1]} + ${BASH_REMATCH[3]:-0} ))
done  <  "student.txt"

printf "total = %d.%d" $((total/10)) $((total%10)
```

output

```
jane is a good student 
annie is a good student 
total = 5.8
```